# Cakephp enable/disable multiple checkbox

Tags: events, cakephp, checkbox

I've been trying to enable or disable multiple checkbox fields using and event triggered by another checkbox.

Checkboxes:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('has_ss',array('label'=>'Los ocupantes de la vivienda ¿Cuentan con seguridad social?'));
    echo $this->Form->input('imss',array('label'=>'IMSS','disabled'=>true));
    echo $this->Form->input('issste',array('label'=>'ISSSTE','disabled'=>true));
    echo $this->Form->input('ssy',array('label'=>'SSY','disabled'=>true));
    echo $this->Form->input('seguro_popular',array('label'=>'Seguro Popular','disabled'=>true));
    echo $this->Form->input('oportunidades',array('label'=>'Oportunidades','disabled'=>true));
    echo $this->Form->input('otro',array('label'=>'Otro','disabled'=>true));

?>
```

The first checkbox is suposed to trigger the event on change and this is the code for that action:

```
$this->Js->get('#BeneficiaryHasSs')->event('change', 
    "if($('#BeneficiaryHasSs').is(':checked')) 
    {
        alert('I'm checked');
    }"
);
```

The alert was only to check if the code was working (which is not) and also with this I would need to check if the main checkbox is checked and enable/disable the others one by one, I would like to know if there's any other way to do this... or at least some help to find out my mistake in the code above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the Cake section but you can do this easily using jQuery.

```
$("#BeneficiaryHasSs").click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        alert("I'm checked");
        $(".commonclass").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $(".commonclass").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Just need to give all the fields that are disabled/enabled together the class commonclass